# Are child elements unmounted before parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

```
const ref_1 = useRef();
const ref_2 = useRef();
const ref_3 = useRef();


<div ref={ref_1}>
  <div ref={ref_2}>
    <div ref={ref_3}>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the `ref_1` is unmounted, will all 3 ref.current become unavailable at once, or is there any order?

Will `ref_3` umount first, then `ref_2` and then `ref_1`?

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question with an interesting answer. They basically unmount at the same time, but under the hood react uses depth-first search algorithm for the unmounting, meaning that in this case the order  is 1, 2, 3. It purely depends on the tree structure.

```
<div ref={ref_1.current}>
  <div ref={ref_2.current}></div>
  <div ref={ref_3.current}></div>
</div>
```

I'm not entirely sure about this part but I think if you look at the code above, 1 will be unmounted first followed by 2 and 3 which are unmounted at the same time. However you shouldn't use the information about which order do they unmount when writing code. If you need a ref after its parent has been unmounted, you should simply save the value before unmounting. Hope that helps!